# Confusion of using Django rest Frame work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So there is a thing I have been very confused about and even after search and watching youtube videos still my concept is not clear. I have created an app with frontend in react and used django rest framework for backend because I know the data that comes from react is in json which normal django doesnt understand. so that's it. Now there is one more app I am working on and my client told me to created an API. Now my questions why would I need an API if the app is only for web can't I use simple django for it? Or not creating an API and directly interacting with the app is bad idea? also can if I create an API do you think I can use it for mobile backend too. How would registration login and logout things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API makes it easier for your client to automate web site management, connect mobile apps, create a richer front-end experience, and integrate your work with other applications. With an API, they can build each new component over time instead of all at once, so a cash-strapped client can start with a web experience, then add a mobile app later. The mobile app could even be made by a different developer, enabling your client to hire a mobile app specialist instead of a general developer.

Registration, login, and logout are very similar to a regular web site.

- You send a POST request to register, including your desired username and password.
- You send a POST request to login and get your authentication token, sending your username and password.
- You send your authentication token as a HTTP header with every request.
- You send another POST request to logout.

You can [read the official Django Rest Framework authentication docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) for details, but it doesn't really tell you how to implement these steps. Check out [this blog post](https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-register-login-logout) instead.

Comment: thanks, Even I am creating a web app do I still need restframework or I can do without it?

Comment: You can do without the Django REST Framework if you are creating a "classic" web app (i.e. it has multiple pages, loads a new page on every action, etc.). If you're creating a single-page web app (i.e. React, Vue, etc.), it's easier to work with a REST API.